# Iterate through objects, destructure, and push to React state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, destructor

I have a grocery list with the following format:

```
{
    'someUniqueId': {
        'category': 'fruit',
        'name': 'apple',
        'checked': 'true'
    },
    'someUniqueId': {
        'category': 'protein',
        'name': 'beef',
        'checked': 'true'
    }
}
```

What I want to do is iterate through this list, destructure each grocery object, then insert into a React state array. This new array would have the following format:

```
data: [
    { 
        category: 'fruit', 
        name: 'apple', 
        header: false, 
        id: 'someUniqueId
    },
    { 
        category: 'protein', 
        name: 'beef', 
        header: false, 
        id: 'someUniqueId
    },
]
```

I'm pretty lost on how to get started with this, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.keys` to get an array of all the keys from the Object. Then use array `map` and inside the callback function create the object with required key value pairs and return it

```js
let obj = {
  'someUniqueId': {
    'category': 'fruit',
    'name': 'apple',
    'checked': 'true'
  },
  'someUniqueId1': {
    'category': 'protein',
    'name': 'beef',
    'checked': 'true'
  }
}
let data = Object.keys(obj).map(function(item) {
  return {
    category: obj[item].category,
    name: obj[item].name,
    header: false,
    id: item
  }


})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need to iterate through the object, simply destructure the object inside a new array.

```
this.state = {
    groceryArray: []
};


const groceryObject = {
    'someUniqueId': {
        'category': 'fruit',
        'name': 'apple',
        'checked': 'true'
    },
    'someUniqueId': {
        'category': 'protein',
        'name': 'beef',
        'checked': 'true'
     }
};


this.setState(prevState => {...prevState, groceryArray : [...prevState.groceryArray, ...groceryObject]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to is to get object keys and values as an array using [`Object.entries`](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=object.entries&oq=Object.ent&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4383j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and then mapping over them

```js
let obj = {
  'someUniqueId': {
    'category': 'fruit',
    'name': 'apple',
    'checked': 'true'
  },
  'someUniqueId1': {
    'category': 'protein',
    'name': 'beef',
    'checked': 'true'
  }
  
}
//console.log(Object.entries(obj))

const res = Object.entries(obj).map(([key,value]) => {
   return {
       ...value,
       id: key
   }
})


console.log(res)
```